# Is this sentence correct in grammar and make sense?

Tags: grammar

> One of the biggest changes has happened in China after the reform and opening is the appearing and growth of Private Enterprises and **for them being identified and recognized**.

I am not sure if this sentence is correct especially in the last part as I want to refer "them" to "Private Enterprises". Is this not clear?

Answer (score 0):

One of the biggest changes to have occurred in China after the reform and opening is the emergence and growth of Private Enterprises that are identified and recognized.